# Onclick на другом объекте

Tags: события, javascript, функции

Задача такова. У меня если элемент (допустим div или textarea) и я хочу, чтобы определенная функция срабатывала, когда я кликаю где угодно, только не на этом объекте. Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var stopElems = []; // в этот массив надо сложить нежелательные элементы
    // напишу код, например, для window
    window.onclick = function(e) {
         var e = e | window.event;
         var stopElemsTotal = stopElems.length; 
         for(var i=0; i<stopElemsTotal; ++i) {
              if(e.srcElement == stopElems[i]) {
                   return;
                   // если это один из нежелательных элементов
                   // просто прекращаем выполнение обработчика
              }
         }
         // тут твой код обработчика
    }
```

Хотя в данном случае, наверное, лучше сделать как-то так:

```
function stopElemClicked(clickedElem, stopElems) {
     var stopElemsTotal = stopElems.length; 
     for(var i=0; i<stopElemsTotal; ++i) {
          if(clickedElem == stopElems[i]) {
               return true;
               // если это один из нежелательных элементов
               // возвращаем истину
          }
     }
     return false; // если нет - ложь
}

onload = function(){
     window.onclick = function(e) {
          var e = e | window.event;
          if(!stopElemClicked(e.srcElement, stopElems)) {
               // тут код обработчика
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: А как обойтись без массива, если элемент у меня всего один

Comment: мде...
ну перепишите тогда

      if(e.srcElement != stopElement) {
               // тут код обработчика
      }

Тогда функция не нужна...

PS:учите матчасть

Answer (score 1):

Задаете для всех объектов событие `onclick()`.
Если там очень много всех элементов, то я бы сделал так:

Помещаете все объекты для вашего клика в какую-нибудь обертку. Возьмем за обертку элемент `DIV`, дадим ему `id="clickWrapper"`. Теперь, когда все объекты в нашей обертке, несложно для всех детей нашего `"clickWrapper"` установить событие `onclick()`:

```
var clickWrapper = document.getElementById('clickWrapper');
//Теперь задаем всем внутренним элементам событие "onclick" ...
for (var childItem in clickWrapper.childNodes) {
    var item = clickWrapper.childNodes[childItem];
    /*Теперь проверяем на то, тот ли это элемент,
      при клике на который не надо вызывать никаких событий...
    */
    if (item.nodeType == 1 //Убеждаемся, что это элемент 
        && item.id!='nonClickableElement'// элемент, на который событие не устанавливаем
        )
            continue;//переходим к следующей итерации
    //А вот тут уже вешаем событие на остальные элементы
    if(item.nodeType == 1){
        item.onclick = function(e){
            //Вот тут ваша функция, которая должна исполняться при клике на элементы
        }
    }
}
```

Для вашего развития более полного в данной ситуации, даю [ссылку](http://js-doc.ru/documentation/dhtml_doc/dhtml03.docs) , где вы сможете подробнее прочитать о `nodeType` элемента.